# DJI Mobile sdk - Telemetry from DJI GO App to personal App

Tags: ios, swift, dji-sdk

I was trying the DJI sdk Sample tutorials and wanted to use the telemetry data for my server. I wanted to know if there is any way in which I can get the Telemetry Data from the existing iOS DJI Go app to my personal iOS app running in the background using the sdk.

Comment: What telemetry data are you trying to get?

Comment: I want the lat, long, altitude, speed, pitch, roll, yaw and heading. If I can get any more data about the drone as well, that would be the icing on the cake.

Answer (score 1):

DJI has UXSDKs that will be easier for you to interface with and collect data from. Here are the links:

1. [iOS UI Library](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-uilib-api/Widgets/AutoExposureLockWidget.html)
2. [Github iOS UXSDK](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS)

Comment: Thanks. I saw these but it doesn't specify how I can get the telemetry data from DJI go app to my app in the background.

Comment: @MuhammadJamaal You can directly access the same type of telemetry data through the SDK that DJIGo uses.

Comment: As @MuhammadJamaal says, you can get the same data but you cannot have multiple apps connecting to the aircraft at the same time so running a background app at the same time as another app is running in the foreground and connected to the aircraft will not work.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain that you cannot access data from 1 app (DJI GO) by another app (your app).

You can create your own app to access the information but that would result in you duplicating the DJI GO app functionality.  (I think that is what Muhammad is suggesting above).

Comment: Is it possible to create an app from SDK, running in the background, that can get the telemetry while I can still fly using the DJI GO app so that I don't have to duplicate all their functionalities. 
I can use " requestAlwaysAuthorization()" and Background Modes -On.